# Renaming field names after joining two tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, rename

When joining two files (*A.csv* and *B.shp* with a common unique `"ID"`) in QGIS the new fields in *B.shp* (from *A.txt*) include the name of the field + the name of the file where it comes from (A).

For example, if we import the field `"gender"` it will appear in *b.shp* as `"A_gender"` not gender only. Now, the problem comes when the field name as very long because when you save the newly joined file (B + A) as a *.shp*, because it only allows field names with a maximum of 10 characters, the field name is truncated.

Any solutions?

Comment: Eduardo, in the past, I have simply added new fields to the shapefile with the field names that fit.  Joining, then using the joined fields to calculate the corresponding new fields.  Not the most efficient approach, but one that works.  It'd be great if a field map view could be edited before saving the layer with a join (allowing for field renaming, of course).  Similar to a feature class to feature class geoprocess in ArcGIS.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can edit how the field names are displayed via the **Alias** widget. I made *Layer A* and *Layer B* (joined to *Layer A*) both containing a *Gender* field.

[image: Layer A attributes]

And you're right about the new shapefile having a limit of 10 characters in its field names.

[image: Layer A + B]

To get around this:

*Layer Properties* > *Fields* and input what you want the field to be called in the **Alias** box.

[image: Field properties]

I simply retyped the original name but you can call it whatever you want.

[image: Result]

Hope this helps!